# Fill the same dataset with different SQL Server stored procedures into datatables

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I would like to fill a dataset from different SQL Server stored procedures (which each return 1 result set) into their own datatables within the dataset.

I don't really want to pass the SQL as text "exec sp1; exec sp2" ... I would like to use the `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure` method like below, what is the best way of doing this?

Clear out the `SqlDataAdapter` and call it again to load it with the sp2 result set? Will it wipe out table(0)? I want it to fill table(1)

```
cnn.Open()
cmdSQL1 = New SqlCommand
cmdSQL1.Connection = cnn
cmdSQL1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmdSQL1.CommandText = ("sp1")
cmdSQL2 = New SqlCommand
cmdSQL2.Connection = cnn
cmdSQL2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmdSQL2.CommandText = ("sp2")

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL1)
da.Fill(ds)
```

edit

```
da.Dispose()
da.SelectCommand = cmdSQL2
da.Fill(ds, "tab2")

dt = ds.Tables(0)
dt2 = ds.Tables(1)
```

Comment: Why not try it and find out?  Set a breakpoint and look at the number of tables in `ds` when that code is done.  The `DataAdapter.Fill()` method is overloaded.  `Fill(ds, string)` lets you create and name the destination table.

Comment: The code *shown* only fills one table (Table(0)) from sp1/cmdSQL1; the second one is never used.  I thought "..." meant you did the same thing for the other one too.

Comment: well is there a way to fill the next table without having to name it like I did "tab2", is there something like a nextresult()?  or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: you dont have to name it, names can be easier to follow rather than `ds.Tables(2)`.  a Const is even better.  You could have a method to fill one table given a "sp" param, and just call it twice.  As is the code repeats itself which is Bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep It Simple. Just look at the example.

```
Dim ds As New Data.DataSet() ' Dataset to fill
Using cnn As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("my connection string")
    Dim cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("sp1", cnn) ' The only command
    cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@id", Data.DbType.Int32)).Value = 1234 ' parameters if we need some
    Dim dt As New Data.DataTable() 
    cnn.Open()
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader()) ' load dt from reader. DataAdapter in fact does the same
    ds.Tables.Add(dt) ' 0th tbl added
    cmd.CommandText = "sp2" ' prepare 2nd SP
    cmd.Parameters.Clear() ' no comment
    dt = New Data.DataTable() ' recreate dt
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
    ds.Tables.Add(dt) ' 1st tbl added
    cnn.Close() ' clean up your place
    cmd.Dispose() ' clean up your place
End Using
```